# Importing .csv files obtained from Calc

Tags: r, read.csv

I am importing a .csv saved from LibreOffice file into R. I have tested these possibilities:

```
vol_determ<-read.csv2("vol_determinac.csv",header = TRUE,dec = ".",sep = ",",
                      fileEncoding="UTF-16LE"
vol_determ<-read.csv("vol_determinac.csv",header = TRUE,dec = ".",sep = ",",
                      fileEncoding="UTF-16LE"
vol_determ<-read.csv("vol_determinac.csv",header = TRUE,dec = ".",sep = ";",
                      fileEncoding="UTF-16LE"
vol_determ<-read.csv2("vol_determinac.csv",header = TRUE,dec = ".",sep = ";",
                      fileEncoding="UTF-16LE"
```

when I do `header(vol_determ)` I get:

```
Nombre.de.la.prueba.abrev.Volumen.de.peticiones.de.pruebas.porc
1                            TIROTROFINA\tTSH\t8899\t8.3876075666607
2   HEMOGRAMA (GLOBULOS BLANCOS)\tHEMOGRAMA \t5274\t4.97092283476441
3                           GLUCOSA\tGLUCOSA\t4163\t3.92376787279565
4                        TIROXINA LIBRE\tT4L\t4132\t3.89454932750219
5                     CREATININA\tCREATININA\t3879\t3.65608829655881
6                       COVID PCR\tCOVID PCR\t3523\t3.32054629254362
```

When I imported the same .csv file obtained from an Excel sheet (2019) this don't happen. Is there any difference between .csv files obtained from  Excel and Calc?

Comment: The `\t` suggests tab separated . Try `read.table(..., sep="\t")`

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Comment: A good first debugging step in trying to read a file is to literally read it—take a peek in a text editor or command line to see what the delimiter is. Yours are tabs, but you've told your code that you have either commas or semicolons